# Revert all commits in local git as well as github?

Tags: git, github, mozilla

I am contributing to Mozilla. I have forked and cloned their repo. I was editing files and changing code a lot of times. When my changes didn't work well, I had to push to my fork on github so that my mentor can view it. git log has a long history of other's commits. What do I need to do to start over? I want my current repo as well as github to the state it was when I forked the repo.

Comment: The easiest is to delete your github repo and fork it again, and then clone it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Identify the commit that you started with when you forked the project.  I'll be referring to this commit as `<SHA>`.
2. Run `git reset --hard <SHA>`
3. Run `git push --force`.

These will still keep the commits that you had done *kind of* accessible, but not in an easy-to-reach manner, and not for very long.  In either event, it will forcibly reset the state of your repository back to what it was at the commit `<SHA>`.

Comment: Also delete branches that have been created since commit `<SHA>` (local and remote branches)  and add `--all` to the forced push. Maybe the reflog will help you to identify those branches and the `<SHA>`.